# Where on the planet Maveth does the sun only rise for a few minutes every 18 years?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

In *Agents of Shield* episode S3E5 "4,722 Hours", Jemma Simmons visits the planet of Maveth, where — at least in her area — the sun only rises for a few minutes every 18 years.

I'm looking for the spot on the planet where Simmons would've been for daylight to have only been visible for such a short time.

Comment: I assume this is meant: http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Maveth

Comment: Due to the way planets rotate both on their axis and around their suns, it's conceivably possible that it wasn't an issue of *where* on the planet they were. Refer to the movie *Pitch Black* for an explained example.

Answer (score 1):

It's mentioned in the show that they are on one of Maveths' poles, presumably Matheth has an eighteen year 'day' and a extremely long 'year'. Simmons would have been there during the late or early winter, the one sunrise every 18 years is analogous to the one hour days that you get In some parts earths poles during winter, after the 'one really big long night' if Simmons had gone a few decades or centuries (its impossible to tell) later it would have been eternal day with a small night every eighteen years.